# Serializing XML with strange namespaces?

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, serialization, xml-serialization

Question: How does the class for the serialization of this XML content look ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vcc:CreateTextSearchResponse xmlns:vcc="urn:veloconnect:catalog-1.1" xmlns:vct="urn:veloconnect:transaction-1.0">
  <vct:BuyersID>12345</vct:BuyersID>
  <vct:ResponseCode>200</vct:ResponseCode>
  <vct:TransactionID>225</vct:TransactionID>
  <vct:StatusCode>2</vct:StatusCode>
  <vct:IsTest>false</vct:IsTest>
  <vcc:TotalCount>3876</vcc:TotalCount>
</vcc:CreateTextSearchResponse>
```

If I let it run through xsd.exe, it generates an error.

I have no problem generating this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CreateTextSearchResponse>
  <BuyersID>15942</BuyersID>
  <ResponseCode>200</ResponseCode>
  <TransactionID>225</TransactionID>
  <StatusCode>2</StatusCode>
  <IsTest>false</IsTest>
  <TotalCount>3876</TotalCount>
</CreateTextSearchResponse>
```

It's just that I need those namespaces to deserialize it (and later on reserialize), so I can't just leave it like this (it's needed by a 3rd party web-service)...

Comment: "it generates an error." is the worst thing to say in a question. Tell us ***what exactly*** it says.

Comment: It says an awful lot, none of it makes any sense at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = CreateTextSearchResponse.CatalogNamespace)]
public class CreateTextSearchResponse
{
    public const string CatalogNamespace = "urn:veloconnect:catalog-1.1",
                TransactionNamespace = "urn:veloconnect:transaction-1.0";
    [XmlElement(Namespace=TransactionNamespace)]
    public int BuyersId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = TransactionNamespace)]
    public int ResponseCode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = TransactionNamespace)]
    public int TransactionID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = TransactionNamespace)]
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = TransactionNamespace)]
    public bool IsTest { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = CatalogNamespace)]
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CreateTextSearchResponse));
    var obj = new CreateTextSearchResponse
    {
        BuyersId = 12345,
        ResponseCode = 200,
        TransactionID = 225,
        StatusCode = 2,
        IsTest = false,
        TotalCount = 3876
    };
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("vcc", CreateTextSearchResponse.CatalogNamespace);
    ns.Add("vct", CreateTextSearchResponse.TransactionNamespace);
    ser.Serialize(Console.Out, obj, ns);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see, now I finally understand what the first parameter of ns.Add is for.

Answer (score -1):

unfortunately there are special characters in your namesapce that Xml can't handle

Comment: sorry. on second glance I can't see any special characters in the namespace so the xml appears to be valid

Comment: No, there aren't. This xml is fine.