# XML serialization - include one XML file in another?

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, serialization, xml-serialization

Question: suppose you have a XML

```
<rootelement>
  <transaction>
    <code>not found</code>
    <status>404</status>
  </transaction>
  <data>
      <item>Whatever</item>
  </data>
</rootelement>
```

And another XML file:

```
<rootelement2>
  <transaction>
    <code>not found</code>
    <status>404</status>
  </transaction>
  <searchresult>
    <item>Whatever</item>
  </searchresult>
</rootelement2>
```

Now, furthermore suppose the tags `transaction`, `searchresult` and `data` are not present, and therefore, their child elements have a namespace instead.

(See here [Serializing XML with strange namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692274/serializing-xml-with-strange-namespaces))

Is there a way I can have one class for everything transaction, one class for everything data, and one class for everything searchresult, and then create a class `SearchResultRequest` which encapsulates `transaction` + its own respective content (without the enclosing tags `<transaction>` and `<searchresult>`),

Something like

```
class SearchResultRequest
{
    <XML_SerializeContentOnly_Here()>
    public cTransaction Transaction = new cTransaction();

    <XML_SerializeContentOnly_Here()>
    public cSearchResult SearchResult = new cSearchResult();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain:
Is there a way I can have one class for everything transaction, one class for everything data, and one class for everything searchresult,

Comment: For your result class, you might try using XElement.Load() for each set and adding the returned XElement to your results.

Comment: Can you write up an example, of how you want a resulting XML to look like, and how resulting class(es) would look like?